# Сложности с кросс-браузерной версткой

Tags: html, css, css3

```
.center{
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.input{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    background-color: #999999;
    padding: 7px 0 5px 0;
    color: #000000;
    text-indent: 7px;
}

.btn{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="center">
<input type="text" class="input"><button type="submit" class="btn">search</button>
</div>
```

[Opera](http://savepic.ru/7858133.png) и [Firefox](http://savepic.ru/7859157.png). Код одинаковый - вид разный. Как это исправить?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=css+%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=deACVvyyMKqoygODoZHgAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница из-за высоты контролов по-умолчанию. Т.к. вы не задали высоту для этих элементов - применяется высота по умолчанию (браузерные стили).
[image: В инспекторе это видно]

В качестве решения: Установите высоту для этих элементов.

```
.input,
.btn {
    height: 14px;
}
```